# Validating input for custom variables in Woocommerce My Account page

Tags: html

I have successfully hooked into the My Account page using woocommerce_edit_account_form and woocommerce_save_account_details, and that seems to be working fine.

The only issue is that I have a field for a mobile phone number that I need to validate to 10 digits (if the mobile notification checkbox is selected), and I cannot seem to find out exactly how and where to add the code.

Wordpress is new to me but I have PHP coding experience.  I did several Google searches, and it looked like woocommerce_save_account_details_errors is the hook I need, but I cannot find any specific samples with the correct syntax to get it to work.

I tried this with no luck (page saved without error message):

```
function my_woocommerce_save_account_details_errors( $user_id ) {

if ( isset( $_POST['mobile_number'] ) )
 {
     if(strlen($_POST['mobile_number'])<6 )
     $args->add( 'error', __( 'Your mobile number must be exactly 10 digits long (5551112222)', 'woocommerce' ),'');
  } 

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
-Ben

Answer (score 1):

try to adapt your code with this one:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details_errors','wdm_validate_custom_field',  10,2 );


function wdm_validate_custom_field(&$args, &$user)
{
    checkFieldEmpty('your_field', 'Label_of_the_Field');

}

function checkFieldEmpty($field_name, $field_label){
     if ( empty( $_POST[$field_name] ) )
    {
        wc_add_notice( '<strong>' . esc_html( $field_label ) . '</strong> ' . __( 'is a required field.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' ); 
    }

}
```